# How do you make an empty named list?

Tags: r, empty-list

In R, the term "empty list" is usually understood to mean `list()`. But this isn't what you get when you delete all the elements from a named list:

```
x = list(a = 1)
x$a = NULL
print(x)                     # named list()
print(identical(x, list()))  # FALSE
```

Is there a slicker or more idiomatic way to get an empty named list?

Comment: Theres a contradiction in what you ask for, as an empty list is different from a named list without values in its named positions. if you want the names you can do it directly a <- list(b=NULL) this is a list with a name of 'b' and no content for b.

Comment: @NirGraham `list(b = NULL)` isn't an empty list, named or otherwise. It has a single element, which is `NULL`. I know it's very confusing that R implements `x$a = NULL` by deleting the named element instead of setting it to `NULL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `setNames`.

```
setNames(list(), character(0))
# named list()
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the code below can play the trick

```
> `[<-`(list(a = NULL), NULL)
named list()

> list(a = NULL)[NULL]
named list()
```

Comment: @Kodiologist Sorry that I misread the question. Probably the update could help.

Comment: This works. It could be more concisely expressed as `list(a = 1)[NULL]`.

Comment: @Kodiologist Yes, true that is more concise.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do

```
a <- list()
attr(a,"names") <- character(0)
a
```

I dont see the value of it though

Comment: This works. It could be more concisely expressed as `attr<-(list(), "names", character())`, but with backticks around `attr<-` (not expressible directly in a comment due to Stack Overflow's limitations on Markdown).

Comment: does this have any application ?

Comment: Yes. In my case, I have a caching function that needs to produce consistent hashes for empty lists, whether they started out empty or they started out with names and then had all elements deleted.

Comment: @NirGraham Yes, I use that in a package (```emptyNamedList <- `names<-`(list(), character(0L))```). This is used for a `shiny` tag object without attributes.

Comment: @Kodiologist Enclose the whole inline code between triple-backticks and you can use single backtick in the code.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Ah, thanks.